# Cannot run Kafka Producer due to socket.error: [Errno 48] Address already in use

Tags: apache-kafka, producer

I have a local docker-machine and I am trying to run a Kafka producer written in python. However, it gives a socket.error: [Errno 48] Address already in use and stopped. Appreciate any helps!

Error Msg:
[image]

Docker machine
[image]

Images on docker-machine
[image]

Containers
[image]

Command to run the producer

```
$ python producer.py
```

P.S. I don't think anything would be wrong in the producer.py, because I ran it successfully a couple days before and I didn't change anything ever since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I already have a process running, which uses the port 9092.

```
sudo lsof -i:9092
```

[image]

So after I kill it, I can run my producer successfully again

```
kill 28987
```

But I remembered I shut down the producer last time I used it, wonder how it was still open...